# Remote Desktop into a Windows 7 PC from a Windows 8 PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, remote-desktop

Is it possible to remote desktop from my Windows 8 laptop into my Windows 7 desktop?

There are a few more things I want to ask about this.

1. When I set up the remote desktop users who can access my Windows 7 desktop, can I specify my Windows 8 credentials?
   I use my Microsoft account to login into my Windows 8 laptop, and I want to use it to log in into my Windows 7 desktop through RDC.
2. I don't have a password for my Windows 7 desktop computer. Do I need to set one?

   ```
    ________________                       __________________
   |Windows 8 Laptop|     ===RDC==>       | Windows 7 Desktop|
   ------------------                     --------------------
   Microsoft Account credentials          Local account, no password
   ```
3. Do I need to set any special settings or permissions? My laptop won't be on the same network as the desktop, but it will be on a secure network.

If you need more information, let me know.

Comment: What Win7/8 editions?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions

Comment: I have Windows 8 Pro on the laptop, and windows 7 Ultimate on my desktop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have a password set up on the remote machine to logon via [RDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol).

You need to allow RDP access on the remote machine.

(Unless you're on a domain.) You need to log on with credentials which are local to that computer. This means, the login credentials on your Windows 8 machine are irrelevant in regards to the connection.

Comment: Is allowing RDP access the only thing I need to do? I looked at some other posts and they mention port forwarding and stuff like that. Do I need to mess with any router settings?

Comment: Yes, there is a good chance. If you're new to this, I suggest you just RDP within the same network. This will then give you some peace of mind that you know how to perform the login and that the connection works. At that stage, consider logging in from remote, but you may have to alter router settings (it does depend on situation)